# Twilio Python - TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, twilio

I am trying to send a test message using twilio with python.

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

import os
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from twilio.rest.resources import Connection
from twilio.rest.resources.connection import PROXY_TYPE_HTTP

proxy_url = os.environ.get("http_proxy")
host, port = urlparse(proxy_url).netloc.split(":")
Connection.set_proxy_info(host, int(port), proxy_type=PROXY_TYPE_HTTP)


account_sid = "ACd9e7ad451565b50cswfewef" # Your Account SID from    www.twilio.com/console
auth_token  = "dcdasfWEfarewgeargfb"  # Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/console

client = TwilioRestClient(account_sid, auth_token)

message = client.messages.create(body="Hello body <3?",
to="+65********",    # Replace with your phone number
from_="+1**********") # Replace with your Twilio number

print(message.sid)
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\...\Python\SendText.py", line 10, in <module>
host, port = urlparse(proxy_url).netloc.split(":")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' enter code here
```

Thoughts: I started by just taking the example phython code from the twilio webpage but it did not seem to work with python 3. So I looked through the internet and found several things to add - I did so and could reduce the list of errors to this (see above). Including a  **decode()** in host, port = urlparse(proxy_url).netloc.decode().split(":") removes this error but simultaneosly produces an other one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\...\Python\SendText.py", line 10, in <module>
host, port = urlparse(proxy_url).netloc.decode().split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: `print` the value of `urlparse(proxy_url).netloc.decode()` before splitting you'll see you don't have `:` in it.

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what you mean - I am a beginner with python. I included both lines:  host, port = urlparse(proxy_url).netloc.decode().split(":")    and                                                                                                                        print ( urlparse(proxy_url).netloc.decode().split(":"))                                          and this produced a new error:host, port = urlparse(proxy_url).netloc.decode().split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: print the value before splitting in blindly. That's what I mean. And don't put code in your comments (specially if it's the same code as in your question)

Comment: Printing the value of host, I still get the same error even if I leave out the  split-part...

Comment: I mean share the value with us.